# What's the difference between Jane Street's ‘Base’, ‘Core’ and 'Core_kernel'?

Tags: ocaml, standard-library, reason, ocaml-core

I'm new to OCaml, and I it's often suggested that I use Jane Street's standard-library instead of the one that ships with the compiler.

However, there seem to even be several of *those*, and I don't know which I should be using:

- [Base](https://github.com/janestreet/base),
- [Core](https://github.com/janestreet/core),
- and [Core_kernel](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel).

Can anybody quickly summarize the difference between these (and perhaps vs. Batteries, etc), or when and why I should choose one over the others?

Comment: For completeness, there's also [core_kernel](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel) which is also by JS, it would be nice to cover it in the answers as well.

Comment: I had exactly that thought, @ÉtienneMillon! 

Comment: I think the Jane Street folks are working on reorganizing some of the documentation and module structure, so hopefully this will all become a little bit clearer in the future.  The *Batteries not Included* and *Containers* libraries are alternatives to the Jane Street libraries, for many purposes.  I find Batteries' documentation easier to navigate than Core, at present, fwiw.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was hoping someone more knowledgable would come along to answer this, but here's the gist of it at least, [straight from the horse's mouth](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/v0-9-release-of-jane-street-packages/253/3):

> - **Base**: minimal stdlib replacement. Portable and lightweight and intended to be highly stable.
> - **Core_kernel**: Extension of Base. More full featured, with more code and dependencies, and APIs that evolve more quickly.
>     Portable, and works on Javascript.
> - **Core**: Core_kernel extended with UNIX APIs.